# If $y_m \to y$ in $H$ then $|y_m|_H \leq C|y|$ for this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces

Let $w_i$ be a basis for a Banach space $V$. We have $V \subset H$ a continuous and dense embedding into a Hilbert space $H$.

Define $y_m = \sum_{i=1}^m a_{im}w_i$. We have that $y_m \to y$ in a $H$ as $m \to \infty$.

Why is it true that $|y_m|_H \leq C|y|_H$?

I don't know why it holds. I found this is Lions "Optimal Control of Systems" beginning at page 100. Also Wloka claims it in page 403.

Comment: I wonder if $y_m$ can be the result of the action of a suitable continuous liner map...

Comment: Siminore please can you expand your hint. The thing is $w_i$ is not orthogonal.